# T-SQL - Receive the gap between 2 Numbers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

I'm receiving a "Max Number" f.e. 201900005 this tells me the range starts at 201900000 (this is given). Now i want to receive the numbers which are missing in this range.

I've looked at several Questions about this, but i can't seem to get it working. Checking the table against itself, using between or using a cursor.

```
Max Number = 201900005, Min Number = 201900000
```

```
test_table
+----------------+
|   test_number  |
+----------------+
|   201900001    |
|   201900003    |
|   201900004    |
+----------------+
```

```
result
+----------------+
|    missing     |
+----------------+
|   201900000    |
|   201900002    |
|   201900005    |
+----------------+
```

The current process works with a "helping"-table which essentally contains all numbers between 201900000 and 201900005 (a lot more in the real situation) and compares those to the onces in the test_table.

I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would would use a Tally to create a list of all the possible numbers, and then `LEFT JOIN` that list to your table and return rows where there is no match:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test_Table (Test_Number int);
INSERT INTO dbo.Test_Table (Test_Number)
VALUES(201900001),(201900003),(201900004);
GO

DECLARE @Start int = 201900000,
        @End int = 201900005;

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP (@End - @Start +1) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 + @Start AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3) --1000 rows, if you need more, just add more
SELECT T.I
FROM Tally T
     LEFT JOIN dbo.Test_Table TT ON T.I = TT.Test_Number
WHERE TT.Test_Number IS NULL;

GO

DROP TABLE dbo.Test_Table;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c47b781b3c498ca5f76185efe8917aa3)

Comment: This is giving me excatly what i want. Could you explain to me what you are doing inside the "WITH"-Statement? I don't really understand how it works...

Comment: I'm using the CTEs to create a Tally, @Frozzo. The first CTE (`N`) just creates 10 rows with the value `NULL`. Then in the second CTE (`Tally`) I create a Cartesian product of the rows in `N`. In the case, as `N` is Cross Joined 3 times, that's 10*10*10 rows = 1,000 rows (as I guess you'll likely need more than 5). I use `TOP` to limit the rows, for performance and use `ROW_NUMBER` to create the incrementing numbers (starting at `@Start` and ending at `@End` due to the `TOP`). The final statement *should* be self explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

Just another option using an ad-hoc tally table and a Union ALL

**Example**

```
Declare @R1 int = 201900000
Declare @R2 int = 201900005

Select Missing = N
 From  (
        Select Top (@R2-@R1+1) N=@R1-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) From  master..spt_values n1, master..spt_values n2 
        Union All
        Select test_number from test_table Where test_number between @R1 and @R2
       ) A
 Group By N
 Having count(*)=1
```

**Returns**

```
Missing
201900000
201900002
201900005
```

Comment: This solution works if i have no number exceeding the "Max Number" (should've added, that this is a property decleared by a user to determine a max range) however if i have a 201900009 for example in my table it will also be displayed

Comment: @Frozzo Fair enough, had I known the USE CASE I would have simply added WHERE TEST_NUMBER between R1 and R2    Either way, I tend to use my Select Top ... for an ad-hoc tally table rather than the CTE.